# Highcharts - Is it possible to add tooltip formatters per series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

im using highcharts to display average and min/max(arearange) values similar to demo http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line, alltough instead of just temperature im also using checkboxes to select ph or flow.

So for example ph change event will redraw with new series

```
dlgElement.find('#ph').on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    propertyType = 'PH';
    propertyAvgItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "averageValue"]);
    propertyMinMaxItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "minValue", "maxValue"]);
    chart.series[0].update({ id: 'series-5', name: 'pH avg.', data: propertyAvgItems});
    chart.series[1].update({ id: 'series-6', name: 'pH min/max', data: propertyMinMaxItems });
    chart.redraw();
});
```

I want to display a tooltip per series so far i have only been able to create one and check per series like this:

```
   tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        enabled: true,
        shared: true,
        formatter: function () {

            var value;
            var propertyUnit;
            var seriesName = this.points[0].series.name;

            if (seriesName == 'Flow') {
                propertyUnit = 'l/s';
            } else if (seriesName == 'Temperature') {
                propertyUnit = String.fromCharCode(186) + "C";
            } else if (seriesName == 'pH') {
                propertyUnit = 'pH';
            }

            if(this.point in this){
                value = this.point.low + " " + propertyUnit + " " + this.point.high + + " " + propertyUnit;
            } else {
                value = this.y;
            }

            return seriesName + " > " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e-%b-%Y', new Date(this.x)) + " :  " + value + " " + propertyUnit;
        }
    },
```

How can i get the boundaries for the arearange, and is it possible to add dinamically per series tooltip using the Highcharts update? Instead of using a global tooltip and checking the series?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, so you need to use single global formatter and then add conditions which will return tooltip per particular serie.

Answer (score 0):

Well i decided to use tooltip/pointformat per series:

```
dlgElement.find('#flow').on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    propertyType = 'FLOW';
    propertyAvgItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "averageValue"]);
    propertyMinMaxItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "minValue", "maxValue"]);
    chart.series[0].update({ id: 'series-1', name: 'Flow avg.', data: propertyAvgItems, tooltip: { pointFormat: '{point.y} l/s<br/>' }});
    chart.series[1].update({ id: 'series-2', name: 'Flow min/max', data: propertyMinMaxItems, tooltip: { pointFormat: '{point.y} l/s<br/>' } });
    chart.redraw();
});

dlgElement.find('#temperature').on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    propertyType = 'TEMPERATURE';
    propertyAvgItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "averageValue"]);
    propertyMinMaxItems = getItems(items, propertyType, ["startDate", "minValue", "maxValue"]);
    chart.series[0].update({ id: 'series-3', name: 'Temperature avg.', data: propertyAvgItems, tooltip: { pointFormat: '{point.y}' + String.fromCharCode(186) + 'C<br/>' }});
    chart.series[1].update({ id: 'series-4', name: 'Temperature min/max', data: propertyMinMaxItems, tooltip: { pointFormat: '{point.y}' + String.fromCharCode(186) + 'C<br/>' }});
    chart.redraw();
});
```